# Help me to resolve this error

Tags: android

I am trying to create a activity for displaying a menu on the emulator screen, by adding this code in my AndroidViews.java file

**AndroidViews.java**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionMenu(Menu menu)
{
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(0,1, Menu.NONE,"M1");
    menu.add(0,2,Menu.NONE, "Button");
    menu.add(0,3,Menu.NONE, "CheckBox");
    return true;

}
```

i am trying to Override the onCreateOptionMenu method of activity class but whenever I have write a Override keyword with the method it will produced an error i.e.
**The method onCreateOptionMenu(Menu) of type AndroidViewsActivity must override or implement a supertype method**

Plz help me out as soon as possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method name should be `onCreateOptionsMenu` (note the extra s). If it still doesn't work you are probably not adding the method to an Activity class.

Comment: but now when i'll run the application then it will not print the menu's on the emulator screen....

Answer (score 5):

It should be

```
onCreateOptionsMenu
              ^
```

If you are working with eclipse, you can choose which methods to override and they'll be added automatically to your class. See [here](http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/eclipse/how-to-override-a-method-from-a-base-class-using-ec.html).

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code hopefully it works for you

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.optionsmenu, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){

    switch (item.getItemId()){

        case R.id.info:
                startActivity(new Intent(this, AboutApp.class));
                return true;

        case R.id.exit:
                finish();
                return true;
    }
  return false;
}
```

and this is the optionsmenu.xml in res/menu/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <item android:id="@+id/info"
          android:title="Info"
          android:icon="@drawable/info_menubtn" />
      <item android:id="@+id/exit"
          android:title="Exit" />
    </menu>
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you are using a version of the Java compiler which supports `@Override`. I would advise using a 1.6 compiler, as the behaviour changed a little from 1.5, and I think that most of the examples that you will find, particularly from [AOSP](http://source.android.com/), are 1.6 compliant.